# Error when installing Ubuntu 14.04 with GTX 970

Tags: 14.04, boot, nvidia, system-installation

I recently tried to install Ubuntu 14.04 on my home computer.
I downloaded the ISO and loaded it onto a compatible USB.
However I get errors when I try to boot Ubuntu.

After browsing this forum I decided that it was probably an incompatibility with my GTX970.
I got nouveau errors, which was fixed by replacing "quiet splash" in the Linux boot line with "text". I found this solution on another post. It only created a new page of errors.

Can anyone please help me to install Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Boot from the USB.**

- Highlight *"Try Ubuntu without installing"*.
- Press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
- Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the `linux` line.
- Press the <kbd>F10</kbd> key to boot into the Live desktop.

**Perform the installation.**

When the Ubuntu system installation process is finished,
unplug the USB and boot into the installed Ubuntu OS.

- Highlight the *"Ubuntu"* GRUB menu entry.
- Press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
- Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the `linux` line.
- Press the <kbd>F10</kbd> key to boot into the Ubuntu system.

**First of all ... install the NVIDIA drivers.**

Comment: Alright, I tried the first half that you suggested (Boot from the USB).
Here's what it looked like after adding nouveau.modeset=0 http://i.imgur.com/uqqn3yU.jpg
The screen went blank for a few seconds then returned this text: http://i.imgur.com/L64dtn0.jpg
Is there any other information that I can provide for you? (Thanks for the help too.)

Comment: @Arrow : You have to add nouveau.modeset=0 without "--" behind it ! :)

Comment: Okay, I tried that and I'm getting the same result.

Comment: @Arrow : Try it with nomodeset instead of nouveau.modeset=0 ! :)

Comment: Dang, you're fast. Still the same result

Comment: @Arrow : Please check whether you can disable the NVIDIA card in BIOS ! :)

Comment: Oh, by the way, this is for a dual boot. I have Windows installed already (forgot to have that in the original post).

Comment: @Arrow : Please get sure that Windows is not in hibernation mode -> http://askubuntu.com/questions/719324/how-to-disable-hibernation-and-fastboot-from-windows-so-dual-boot-works-in-ubunt/719391#719391

Comment: GASP. It's working. Okay here's what I did. Go into ASROCK UEFI Settings, switched to onboard graphics, unplugged my monitor, from the gpu and plugged it into the motherboard. Disabled Windows hibernation. Booted from USB, and used nomodeset.

Comment: Okay, so now an install option for Ubuntu is popping up. Should I install it now. Or should I turn off and unplug the USB, as listed above. (Also, does it seem possible that I'll still be able to access my GPU, in Ubuntu, after setting this up).

Comment: @Arrow : First boot into the Ubuntu Live desktop as described (Try Ubuntu without installing), then install Ubuntu ... when the OS installation is finished ... reboot ... you are getting asked to remove the USB then. :)

Comment: Okay. Do I need to install the NVIDIA Drivers before I switch back to PCI (instead of onboard) graphics in the UEFI settings?

Comment: @Arrow : Sorry - this I do not know (every hardware is different) - important is to install the NVIDIA drivers before installing something else, afterwards you don't have to set a parameter before booting anymore. :)

Comment: Thanks so much, you've been a great help and handled my tech ignorance :D