# How to install Ubuntu 18.04.4 alongside Windows 10 on laptop

Tags: dual-boot

I have Dell G3 3590 i5 9300H, GTX1650, 8GB RAM, 256SSD(Windows 10),1TB HDD(Data Storage).

I have already allocated 300GB of the 1TB HDD to Ubuntu from windows disk management tool. How can I successfully install Ubuntu in dual boot next to windows 10.

I have already tried doing that before but went into a bootloop and couldn't boot past DELL BIOS logo.

Things I've done: I have partitioned 40GB to /, 12GB to /swap, and the rest of the 300GB to /home.
Installation finished successfully and asked for a restart afterwards the laptop went into a deep bootloop while not being able to boot into either OSes weirdly enough I couldn't even change the boot sequence in BIOS.

I've formatted both disks and installed a fresh copy of windows 10 now and I need to reinstall Ubuntu because I need it for my University.

So if there's a safe guide for my specific setup here i'd be really happy.
Thanks in advance!
.

So apparently, as the awesome community have told me the key is to turn off windows FastBoot & Hibernation as well as if you have a Dell laptop put the BIOS Boot Mode into Audit Mode.

Really appreciate the help guys! Thank you so much !

Comment: Back to basics: Did you remember to turn off Windows FastBoot?

Comment: Sorry do you mean disable Secure Boot from BIOS?

Comment: Fast Boot and Secure Boot are different terms you could search for.

Comment: No actually I didn't... So next time I attempt installing Ubuntu I should turn off Windwos FastBoot and turn off Hibernation as well?

Comment: You could read this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/477740/341457 But this suggestion could not be 100% working in your case.

Comment: And if so, should I keep both options turned off after installing Ubuntu or turn them back on after successfully having a dual-boot system?

Comment: Yes, Windows Hibernation and Fast Startup should not be used in a dual boot system. https://askubuntu.com/questions/719324/how-to-disable-hibernation-and-fastboot-from-windows-so-dual-boot-works-in-ubunt provides additional detail;

Comment: Thanks a lot guys!, will post after I try installation

Comment: Thanks to each one of you, it really saved me a lot of work!